# How to change Y axis without excluding data (outliers not shown but accounted for median)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis, outliers

A draw a boxplot with ggplot2:

```
ggplot(datasilice, aes(x = Duree_exposition_4gpes, y = CD25plusCD127moinsFoxP3plus_num)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill= Duree_exposition_4gpes), colour = "black", outlier.shape = 1, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 160), breaks = seq(0,160,20))
```

I get this:

[with outliers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pczQz.png)

I don't want to show outliers, so, I change my code to:

```
ggplot(datasilice, aes(x = Duree_exposition_4gpes, y = CD25plusCD127moinsFoxP3plus_num)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill= Duree_exposition_4gpes), colour = "black", outlier.shape = NA, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 160), breaks = seq(0,160,20))
```

And I get this:

[without outliers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUWa0.png)

So far, so good.
Now, I want to reduce my Y axis, so I reduce limits and breaks:

```
ggplot(datasilice, aes(x = Duree_exposition_4gpes, y = CD25plusCD127moinsFoxP3plus_num)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill= Duree_exposition_4gpes), colour = "black", outlier.shape = NA, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 120), breaks = seq(0,120,20))
```

But now look at how the median for 2nd column has been modified?

[changed median](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYE3A.png)

So my question is, how can I change Y axis without excluding data (outliers not shown, but accounted for median) ?

I tried to modify only "breaks" or only "limits" but it doesn't do what expected...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is not intuitive behavior (at least it gives a warning message).... You need to use `coord_cartesian` to simply zoom in without changing the data.
Cf.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg)) + 
+     geom_boxplot(aes(fill= cyl, group=cyl), colour = "black", outlier.shape = NA, show.legend = FALSE) +
+     coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,25))
```

vs.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg)) + 
+     geom_boxplot(aes(fill= cyl, group=cyl), colour = "black", outlier.shape = NA, show.legend = FALSE) +
+     scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,25))
```